# Type Is not defined - C# class to VB.NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, entity-framework

I am sitting with a rather strange error - which I believe I followed the correct steps to solve.

Basically, My compiler complains about the following:

`Type 'InteractionsEntities' is not defined`

Here is an explanation of all I have done. My goal is to use a class compiled in C# within my vb.net project.

**Step 1**: Right clicked my VB.NET project - Add > Reference

**Step 2**: Out of the project list, I selected my C# project containing the `InteractionsEntities` class and pressed Ok.

**Step 3**: I added the line of code in my vb.net module: `Imports CsharpProject.CsharpNamespace`

**Step 4**: Within my module, I added a variable: `Private context = new InteractionsEntities` -- note on this point, Intellisense was able to find the class I required.

**Step 5**: To ensure my Project can use entity framework, I used the nuget package manager to install entity framework.

So following the steps I listed above, I have the following code:

```
Imports CsharpProject.CsharpNamespace

Module Module1
    Dim context = New InteractionsEntities()
    Sub Main(properties As String())
            Dim documents = context.Documents.Select(Function(x) x)
            For Each document In documents
                Console.WriteLine(document.Name)
            Next
    End Sub
```

What is strange is that Intellisense was able to detect that InteractionsEntities existed in my C# namespace. Upon Installing the entityframework nuget package, the error would disappear - and I was able to access properties within the context variable. The moment I hit "rebuild all" - the error `Type 'InteractionsEntities' is not defined` returns. Hovering over the namespace (which also gets marked as erroneous now) and clicking the `Error Corrections Options` yields no Correction Suggestions.

Have I missed a step inbetween? Why is my VB.NET project complaining that the class does not exist when it does? I have tested with other classes under the c# namespace too (which has nothing to do with the entity framework) and the same effect occurs.

Comment: Is the error reproduced if you Clean your solution, then manually build your C# project first, and VB project after?

Comment: That's an idea. Let me clean and rebuild the solutions in order you listed

Comment: Sadly the error still occurs

Comment: That also didn't help @SébastienSevrin. It is a valid Idea you're posting there, and trust me - I have tried it (and went less and less fancy with each try trying to find the root cause of the problem). I managed to solve the issue by checking which .NET framework each project compiles to - which mismatched in my case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Wow ok. I found the problem.

When this happens, ensure that your C# project and VB.NET project are at least compiled in the same .NET Framework version.

My inspection in my project was the following:

1. Right-click C# Project > Properties > Application > Look at target Framework (my case it was 4.5.1)
2. Repeat the steps for the VB.NET Project > Properties > Application > Look at target Framework (my case it was 4.5)
3. Set the .NET Framework of the VB.NET Project to match that of the C# Project and click yes in the dialog box which pops up.
4. Rebuild project

This fixed my issue.

Comment: Interesting. According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433108/can-you-mix-net-framework-versions-in-a-solution), it should be a problem.

Comment: I only wonder why they haven't added warnings or somesuch when you add a reference to your project with a .NET Framework version which is higher than your current. Instead it gave me a detour by giving me different compile time errors which had nothing to do with what the actual issue was

Comment: I believe that if your VB project was targeting a later version it would probably work as well. Good job finding the answer yourself, though you might want to generalize the question a bit.